# pandas groupby and create new columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe look like this:

```
user_id article_id  set_tags
1            31       true
1            32       false
1            35       false
2            11       false
2            11       true
3            56       true
```

I want to get the result like this:

```
user_id total_articles  set_tags_true   set_tags_false
   1      3                    1               2
   2      2                    1               1
   3      1                    1               0
```

I'm new to this, how can i do this?
I tried to use groupby.count(), but it doesn't seem like it's correct.

Comment: Should the total_articles column for user_id 2 be 2 or 1?

Comment: @PhilipEgger my fault, it should be 2

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = [[1,31,True],[1,32,False],[1,35,False],[2,11,False],[2,11,True],[3,56,True]],
    columns=['user_id','article_id','set_tags']
)
df
   user_id  article_id  set_tags
0        1          31      True
1        1          32     False
2        1          35     False
3        2          11     False
4        2          11      True
5        3          56      True

output_df = df.groupby('user_id').agg({'article_id':'nunique', 'set_tags':['sum', (lambda x:sum(~x))]})
output_df.columns = ['total_articles','set_tags_True','set_tags_False']
output_df
         total_articles  set_tags_True  set_tags_False
user_id                                               
1                     3              1               2
2                     1              1               1
3                     1              1               0
```

If you want the total_articles entry for user_id 2 to be 2 instead of 1, just replace nunique with count.

Comment: oops I have a problem here, can you explain please why it's happening? 
if i fulfill dataframe like this: 
`
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = [['1','10001963',True],['2','40014',True],['2','40017',False],['1','40057',True]],
    columns=['user_id','article_id','set_tags']
)
`
as an result for set_tags_False i got: 
False
True